# Jmeter- How to load test a upload file inside a login session?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-5.0

Scenario to test:

step 1: Login with username and password
step 2:go to  upload page
step 3:select a file and click upload(POST request)- Need to do load testing on this POST request.

My setup in JMeter- login and go the the upload page is set with for example 10 threads in 5 ramp up time.

Then,I have tried with synchronization timer under the upload POST request. So, now what happens is 10 logins happens in 5 seconds and after that the 10 upload POST request is send at the same time.

What I need is,

Since I do not want to test the load of login, I do not want to make these 10 logins requests to be send to server. And I cannot pass the session ID in upload POST request since our system is having so much of  authentication of a user with uuid and JWT token. Is there a possible way to do this much simpler?

Jmeter Version is 3.2

Answer (score 0):

If you won't be logged in my expectation is that the upload request will fail. You might come up with the relevant [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configuration like define ramp-up period higher than response time so you will not have any concurrency on login.

Later on you can use [Filter Results tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) in order to exclude "not interesting" requests from the .jtl results file.

Filter Results Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image]

You might also need [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) tool as well.